# Function definition with guards

Tags: haskell

Classic way to define Haskell functions is

```
f1 :: String -> Int
f1 ('-' : cs) -> f1 cs + 1
f1 _ = 0
```

I'm kinda unsatisfied writing function name at every line. Now I usually write in the following way, using pattern guards extension and consider it more readable and modification friendly:

```
f2 :: String -> Int
f2 s
  | '-' : cs <- s = f2 cs + 1
  | otherwise = 0
```

Do you think that second example is more readable, modifiable and elegant? What about generated code? (Haven't time to see desugared output yet, sorry!). What are cons? The only I see  is extension usage.

Comment: In `f2` you would have to repeat the `<- s` part for each pattern. It depends on your taste.

Comment: So I will use old-school case:) It case one drawback: it can't match on multiple args: `f 0 _ = []; f _ [] = []; f n (x:xs) = f (n-1) xs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer writing function name when I am pattern matching on something as is shown in your case. I find it more readable.

I prefer using guards when I have some conditions on the function arguments, which helps avoiding `if else`, which I would have to use if I was to follow the first pattern.

So to answer your questions

```
Do you think that second example is more readable, modifiable and elegant?
```

No, I prefer the first one which is simple and readable. But more or less it depends on your personal taste.

```
What about generated code?
```

I dont think there will be any difference in the generated code. Both are just patternmatching.

```
What are cons?
```

Well patternguards are useful to patternmatch instead of using let or something more cleanly.

```
addLookup env var1 var2
   | Just val1 <- lookup env var1
   , Just val2 <- lookup env var2
   = val1 + val2
```

Well the con is ofcourse you need to use an extension and also it is not Haskell98 (which you might not consider much of a con)

On the other hand for trivial pattern matching on function arguments I will just use the first method, which is simple and readable.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you could always write it like this:

```
f3 :: String -> Int
f3 s = case s of
           ('-' : cs) -> f3 cs + 1
           _          -> 0
```

Which means the same thing as the `f1` version. If the function has a lengthy or otherwise hard-to-read name, and you want to match against lots of patterns, this probably would be an improvement. For your example here I'd use the conventional syntax.

There's nothing wrong with your `f2` version, as such, but it seems a slightly frivolous use of a syntactic GHC extension that's not common enough to assume everyone will be familiar with it. For personal code it's not a big deal, but I'd stick with the `case` expression for anything you expect other people to be reading.